# WP: The Events Calendar change language

Tags: php, jquery, calendar, wordpress

I have a question on WordPress plugin "[The Events Calendar](http://wordpress.org/plugins/the-events-calendar)".
I want to change is contents into my language.

Unfortunately, I have no idea even how to start doing it.

For example I want to change the line "FIND EVENTS" (the main search button) to some other content. Where i can find this line in the plugin code?

Thanks you all :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make a copy of the file `plugins/the-events-calendar/lang/tribe-events-calendar.pot` and rename it to **`the-events-calendar-xx_XX.po`**.

- `xx_XX` is `language_COUNTRY`, **the same as defined** for `WPLANG` in `wp-config.php`, see [Installing_WordPress_in_Your_Language](http://codex.wordpress.org/Installing_WordPress_in_Your_Language)
- Note the different file extention, `pot` and `po`
- Once you have this file, download [PoEdit](http://www.poedit.net/) for your platform and open the file.
- Now you can start translating (translate only a couple of sentences first)
- When you save the file, PoEdit will generate another file: **`the-events-calendar-xx_XX.mo`**. That's the one that you have to upload to the plugin `lang` folder.

When you update the plugin you lose this file and it needs to be uploaded again. How to prevent this? Send the files (`po` and `mo`) to the plugin author, so s/he includes it and everyone benefits.